# Application of the Hahn-Banach theorem to the subspace $C[0,1]$ of $L[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X=L[0,1]$ and let $Y=C[0,1]$. Choose $x_0$ in the interval $(0,1)$ and let $\ell(f)=f(x_0)$ for $f\in Y$. Is it possible to extend $\ell$ to a bounded linear functional on $X$?

I would like to answer this question by using the real version of the Hahn-Banach theorem. It's quite easy to show that $\ell$ is a linear functional on $Y$, but it remains to find, if any, a sub-linear functional $p$ on $X$ s.t. $\ell\leq p$ on $Y$. After this, one can apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to find a linear functional $\hat{\ell}$ on $X$ s.t. $\hat{\ell}\leq p$ on $X$ and $\hat{\ell}=\ell$ on $Y$. Following this, we further ask whether $\hat{\ell}$ can be chosen to be bounded. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is an extension of $\ell$ to a bounded linear functional $L$. Define $f_n(x)=n(\frac  1 n -|x-x_0|)$ for $|x-x_0| \leq \frac 1 n$ and $0$ for $|x-x_0| > \frac 1 n$. Since each $f_n$ is continuous we have $L(f_n)=\ell (f_n)=f_n(x_0)=1$. Hence $1=L(f_n) \leq \|L\| \|f_n\|_1$ I will let you check that $\|f_n\|_1 \to 0$ leading to a contradiction.

Comment: In fact this shows that not only there is no bounded linear extension, but that $\ell$ itself is not bounded to begin with, so there was no hope to find a bounded extension.

Comment: @themaker Yes. In fact $L[0,1]$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ so if $\ell$ were continuous it would have a unique continuous extension.

Comment: Is $L[0,1]$ really dense in $C[0,1]$? I suppose the contrary.

Comment: @Steve Right.  I meant it that other way.